# Confusing definitions of matrix coherence in linear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am having two different definitions of **matrix coherence**.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_coherence_(linear_algebra)) (and its assorted references) defines it as follows: *"the coherence or mutual coherence of a matrix A is defined as the maximum absolute value of the cross-correlations between the columns of A."*

However, there are machine learning [paper(s)](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v15/mohri11a/mohri11a.pdf) that define it as *"Matrix coherence measures the extent to which the
singular vectors of a matrix are correlated with the
standard basis".*

Are these two different definitions of two different quantities, or is there some relation between the two?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the "the cross-correlations between the columns of A" corresponds to find the singular values of the Gramian of A =AA`. The maximum of the singular values gives you a singular vector such that when you do the internal product with the columns of A you will get which row has the maximum coherence. So, in a way both descriptions will lead to identify the max coherence row of A.